# C++ Vector of template class, Polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, generics, vector, polymorphism

Every time that I create a object, I store the pointer of that object in a vector, which is a static member of the class of the object, in order to monitor its state, something like this:

```
class A {
private:
    static std::vector<A *> as;
    STATE state = NONE; //<- enum
    void doSomething();

public:
    A() {
        as.push_back(this);
    }

    static void monitor() {
        auto end = as.end();

        for (auto obj = as.begin(); obj != end; obj++) {
            switch ((*obj)->state) {
                //process it
                (*obj)->doSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}

//// recurrent call in other part of the program or even in other thread
A::monitor();
```

The above code is obviously incomplete, lacks an appropriately destructor, to remove the pointer of the vector that is being deleted.

the problem now is that I have to do the same with a template class

```
template <typename T>
class A {            

    void doSomething(); //<--independent, no template
    ....
}
```

Is there any way to do the same?, applying the independent type method "doSomething()" for every object?

If the function "doSomething()" was dependent type, there would be a way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
private:
    static std::vector<A<T>*> as;
    STATE state = NONE; //<- enum
    void doSomething()

public:
    A() { as.push_back(this); }

    static void monitor() {
        auto end = as.end();

        for (auto obj = as.begin(); obj != end; obj++) {
            switch ((*obj)->state) {
                //process it
                (*obj)->doSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<A<T>*> as;
```

You just have to call

```
A<MyType>::monitor();
```

Comment: that's a really good solution, but I'm planning to use the class as a kind of interface, so, the fact that make the call for every <type> is a little bit tedious.

Comment: @quetzalfir: So it seems you want every `class A<T>` to derive from some `Base` (where you can move that implementation), and then do `Base::monitor();`